# Mistakenly edited someone's community wiki

Tags: support

I recently answered a question on Stack Overflow about C++ vector slicing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1110548/12452330), however as I was editing that community wiki, I inadvertently introduced changes that conflicted with that author's intent. By the time I realized this it was too late and my edit was already pending peer review (and I couldn't find any option to discard the review). So I made my own answer in that question and hoped that whoever saw this review would see that the edit would make two identical answers and discard it.

Unfortunately, someone accepted the edit so right now there are two answers there which are nearly identical. I'm sorry and I'm writing this here hoping that someone will notice this and roll back the edit I made.

Comment: Edit rolled back.  That didn't exactly hurt that post btw.

Comment: For some reason I still see the "This edit will be visible only to you" banner.

Comment: You probably have to refresh the page, press F5.

Comment: That worked. It's gone now.

Comment: Well, now the problem is *why* reviewers chose to approve this edit ;)

Comment: Anyone who would have *rejected* that edit would have been wrong, @double. It’s a good edit that materially improves the answer without changing the author’s intent. It’s one of the best edits I’ve seen in a long time.

Comment: @CodyGray I wholly disagree, that edit should have been a new answer from the beginning (kudos to OP for realising that). Under the [popular code review dupe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code) don'ts, you shouldn't *"change the code logic or functionality"*, and reviewers *aren't expected to review suggestions that do* and they should be *rejected*. Why would reviewers not be expected to review edits to code but would be expected to review new code?

Comment: @Nick Adding an example to a minimal answer is not changing the code logic or functionality. Improving an answer from the bare-minimum to something useful by adding an example is above and beyond, an example of a stellar review. If a reviewer isn't sure that the example is relevant, then they should Skip that review.

Comment: @CodyGray But does the example match the previous version of the answer? It originally said "use a pair of iterators" and OPs answer said "you don't need a pair of iterators" together with that code example. I don't know C++ much, but to me it reads like the code shows something else than what the answer text suggests.